# Oracle's SDO_CONTAINS not using spatial index on unioned tables?

Tags: oracle, union, spatial

I'm trying to use Oracle's sdo_contains spatial operator, but it seems, that it's not really working, when you use it on unioned tables.
The below code runs in 2 mins, but you have to duplicate the spatial operator for every source table:

```
SELECT -- works
   x.code,
   count(x.my_id) cnt
FROM (select
         c.code,
         t.my_id
      from my_poi_table_1 t,my_shape c
      WHERE SDO_contains(c.shape,
                   sdo_geometry(2001,null,SDO_POINT_type(t.latitude, t.longitude,null),null,null)
                   ) = 'TRUE'
      union all
      select
         c.code,
         t.my_id
      from my_poi_table_2 t,my_shape c
      where SDO_contains(c.shape,
                   sdo_geometry(2001,null,SDO_POINT_type(t.lat, t.lng,null),null,null)
                   ) = 'TRUE'
      ) x
group by x.code
```

I wanted to make it simple, so I tried to first create the points, and then just once use the sdo_contains on it, but it's running for more then 25 mins, because it's not using the spatial index:

```
SELECT -- does not work
   c.code,
   count(x.my_id) cnt
FROM my_shape c,
     (select
         my_id,
         sdo_geometry(2001,null,SDO_POINT_type(latitude, longitude,null),null,null) point
      from my_poi_table_1 t
      union all
      select
         my_id2,
         sdo_geometry(2001,null,SDO_POINT_type(lat, lng,null),null,null) point
      from my_poi_table_2 t
      ) x
WHERE SDO_contains(c.shape,
                   x.point
                   ) = 'TRUE'
group by c.code
```

Is there a way to use the sdo_contains on the results of multiple tables without having to include it in the select several times?
Oracle: 12.1.0.2

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that sdo_contains cannot (efficiently) read from a subselect: if I put one of the poi tables into a subselect, then Oracle will not use spatial index for that part:

```
SELECT -- does not work
   x.code,
   count(x.my_id) cnt
FROM (select --+ ordered index(c,INDEX_NAME)
         c.code,
         t.my_id
      from my_shape c,(select t.*,rownum rn from my_poi_table_1 t) t
      WHERE SDO_contains(c.shape,
                   sdo_geometry(2001,null,SDO_POINT_type(t.latitude, t.longitude,null),null,null)
                   ) = 'TRUE'
      union all
      select
         c.code,
         t.my_id
      from my_poi_table_2 t,my_shape c
      where SDO_contains(c.shape,
                   sdo_geometry(2001,null,SDO_POINT_type(t.lat, t.lng,null),null,null)
                   ) = 'TRUE'
      ) x
group by x.code
```